# using tensorflow fill method to create a tensor of certain datatype

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, tensor

I am trying to use the `tf.fill()` method to create a tensor of different data types(float16,float32,float64) similar to what you can do with `numpy.full()`. would tf.constant() be a suitable substitution? or should I create my fill values to be of the data type I want them to be then plug it into the value holder inside `tf.fill()`

Answer (score 2):

You can use `fill`. However, the resulting type will depend on the `value` argument, you cannot control the resulting type with an explicit `dtype` argument. That is indeed a bit different from most other tensorflow operators.

```
tf.fill([2, 3], 9) # tensor with dtype=int23
tf.fill([2, 3], 9.0) # tensor with dtype=float32
# more explicit
tf.fill([2, 3], np.float64(9)) # tensor with dtype=float64
```

Answer (score 1):

You can either provide the value of the datatype you want your resulting tensor to be or to cast a tensor afterwards.

1. `tf.fill((3, 3), 0.0)` # will be a float 32
2. `tf.cast(tf.fill((3, 3)), tf.float32)` # also float 32

The first one is better because you use less operations in the graph